# Merge sort algorithm(merging array part)

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, data-structures

Question is about the merge sort from a video starting from 16:43 to 23:34
http://youtu.be/M814OagXWTI?t=16m43s

I am confused how we are merging back these subarrays after exiting our left/right sort merge recursions. Lets start at the very bottom when our elements are split into two subarrays, a left subarray know as B and a right subarray know as C. At around 16:43 we jump into the merge function and sort array B and C which is just 8 and 3. The merge sort function(code bellow) basically compares elements of B with C through indexes. Starting from element 0 we compare each element from both arrays and whichever is smallest gets added to array A. We increase our index of whichever array that element came from etc until we basically have a sorted array. After our sorted array we are finished so we exit the recursion call that we were in to crawl back up the recursion stack that was previously paused and proceed splitting the right side of our subarray 8 3 2 9.

We basically do what we did above and again exit the recursion call that we were in and proceed to merging 3 8 2 9. **Okay this is my question:** I am seeing a contradiction here in the code. We fed our merged elements back to our Array A but when we call the merge function to merge 2 8 and 2 9 we are passing array B, C, and A. We are then using array B and C to do the comparison but the elements we want to sort are in A are they not? So wouldn't it just be sorting the wrong things? I really need some clarification on this part.

Pseudo code:

```
 MergeSort(A[0...n-1]){
if n<=1
    return A;

copy A[0...n/2-1] to B[0...n/2-1]
copy A[n/2...n-1] to C[0...n/2-1]
MergeSort(B[0...(n/2)-1)
MergeSort(C[0...(n/2)-1)
Merge(B,C,A)

Merge(B[0...p-1], C[0...q-1], A[0...p+q-1]){
i=0; j=0; k=0
while( i <p and j<q) do{
    if B[i] <= C[j] {
        A[k]=B[i];
        i=i+1;
    }
    else {
    A[k]=C[j];
    j=j+1;
    }
    k=k+1
}

//Copy leftover element
if i==p
    A[k...p+q-1]=C[j...q-1]
else
    A[k...p+q-1]=B[i...p-1]
}
```

Comment: A is a formal argument identifier, so it means different things in different invocations of MergeSort.

Comment: This does not answer my question.

Comment: After the recursion to split 2 and 9 we try one more time to recursively call MergeSort(C[0...(n/2)-1) on subarray 9 but because it is only one element we exit that recursive call and emerge out of MergeSort(C[0...(n/2)-1) and proceed on to the next statement which is Merge(B,C,A). We merge arrays B and C which are 2 and 9 into array A and then exit that recursion call in order to go back to the previous paused recursive call.

Comment: In this recursive call we finished both MergeSort(B[0...(n/2)-1) and now MergeSort(C[0...(n/2)-1) - which is where we came out of. The next statement would then be to merge both sides but the code uses B and C to merge while we previously stored what we merged in array A. I dont see how this would work, we would be merging what B and C were in this recursion call which i believe to be B=8,3  C=2,9. The code never splits back A into B and C since we go directly from sorting the right side to merging.

Comment: Call a particular MergSort invocation X. X calls MergeSort invocation Y to sort X's B. What Y calls A, the place where Y leaves its sorted data, is what X calls B. X calls MergeSort invocation Z to sort X's C. What Z calls A, the place where it leaves its sorted data, is what X calls C. On return from Z, X's B and C are sorted, and X merges them into X's A. Unless X is the top level call, that is either B or C for the X's caller.

Comment: You totally lost me... could you please put this in perspective of sorting the left side of array 8 3 2 9 7 1 5 4 so 8 3 2 9 etc? Also using these x y variables makes it confusing to understand.

Comment: Also you said "X calls MergeSort invocation Y to sort X's B. " but mergesort does not do the sorting, the invocation of the merge function does the sorting. Do you mean to split?

Comment: Your basic problem is that you are assuming that variables and formal arguments mean the same thing in different invocations of MergeSort. You **must** find some way to label different invocations so that you can think about and discuss their variables. If you don't like X, Y, and Z, think of your own names. The labels do not matter as long as you stop confusing A in one invocation with A in a different one. According to the code you posted, MergeSort calls Merge, so by the time a MergeSort invocation returns its A is sorted.

Comment: You are saying that after we sort A by merging the two subarrays B and C and exit the recursion call to go back up the stack then A in this recursion call is different then the A in the previous recursion call we just exited from? If so i'm even more confused because then we just lost our merged sorted array. It would really help if you could give detailed steps so i can follow what you are doing through the recursions.

Comment: Besides your question, you have a bug in the 2nd line: n > 1 is not the base case and rather than return n, you should return A if n <= 1.

Comment: I think if i understand what you are saying:

You are saying that the array A from recursion Y when merging B and C into A is equal to the array B in recursion X. How is that possible?

Comment: It is possible because each invocation of a method gets its own stack frame, with its own argument values and its own local variables. The stack can contain a dozen different MergeSort frames at the same time.

Comment: I'm still not seeing the connection on how those two arrays relate if they are/everything is different.

Comment: never mind i think i finally get it but what made it so hard for me to understand is the code's lack of return statements. Like how the merge function should be returning array A and storing it from our merge argument located in the mergesort function and which then our mergesort function should return that array back to the previous recursion which would be either one of the mergesort arguments and have it stored are B or C. Then i can understand how B or C equals A and we can merge them.

Comment: The call to MergeSort is passing the array by reference, rather than by value. Each invocation of MergeSort changes the array it is passed from possibly non-sorted to definitely sorted. Each non-base invocation creates a B and a C, copying half its A into each of them, calls itself to sort each, then merges them back into its A.

Comment: So if we wanted to do this by pass-by-value instead, adding the return statements would make it work by what i said above?

Comment: You could use pass-by-value and return statements, but that is not usually done for sorting an array because of the extra data copying.

Comment: But wouldnt that be the only way in Java as you cannot pass by reference?

Comment: In Java, you can only pass by value, but for any object, including an array, what is passed by value is a reference that points to the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a blow-by-blow narration of a simple sort using the quoted algorithm. Indentation represents stack depth. Each MergeSort or Merge invocation is numbered in time order. A3 means the A array in invocation 3. "==" means "is equivalent to". "=" means "has content".

Suppose Top has an array Original, content {3,4,2,1}. Top calls MergeSort(Original)

```
MergeSort1(A1==Original={3,4,2,1}) Create B1={3,4} and C1={2,1}
  MergeSort2(A2==B1={3,4}) Create B2={3} and C2={4}
    MergeSort3(A3==B2={3}) Base case, no changes.
    MergeSort4(A4==C2={4}) Base case, no changes.
    Merge5(B5==B2={3},C5==B2={4},A5==A2==B1) Write {3,4} into A5, which is A2, which is B1.
  MergeSort6(A6==C1={2,1}) Create B6={2} and C6={1}
    MergeSort7(A7==B6={2}) Base case, no changes.
    MergeSort8(A8==C6={1}) Base case, no changes.
    Merge9(B9==B6={2},C9==C6={1},A9==A6==C1) Write {1,2} into A9, which is A6, which is C1.
  Merge10(B10==B1={3,4},C10==C1=={1,2},A10==A1==Original) Write {1,2,3,4} into A10, which is A1, which is Original.
```

The high level result of all this is to replace {3,4,2,1} in Original with {1,2,3,4}.

The key point to remember is that each function invocation has its own stack frame, with its own variables, but that its formal argument is mapped to an actual argument that is a variable or parameter in its caller's frame.